# how to understand excel formulas?( To convert it to sql query)

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

I have some complex Excel formulas which I plan to convert to oracle/sql as part of an automation process, 
The main problem i see is the difficulty in the readablilty of various excel formulas that are used, pasting one such sample here, 
Any help suggestion on how to decode these formulas will be helpful. The other question- is there a feasible way to convert formulas involving vlookup to a sql query?

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(6000301407,[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(6003921231,[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(6001089085,[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(6011995534,[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(6008725372,[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(6013991835,[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]])),VLOOKUP([@[Snapshot Sold To Industry Key Dsc]],Licensee_List[#All],2,0),"No"),"Yes"),"No"),"Yes"),"No"),"No")`

Comment: Begin by separating it into multiple lines and indenting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your formula tries to find those numeric values (starting with `60...`) in string value called `[@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]]`. The flow is like following:

```
Search in [@[Snapshot Sold To Cust Id]]: 
Found 6000301407? Print "No".
    Else
    Found 6003921231? Print "No".
        Else
        Found 6001089085? Print "Yes".
            Else
            Found 6011995534? Print "No".
                Else
                Found 6008725372? Print "Yes".
                    Else
                    Found 6013991835? Print "No".
                        Else
                        Search [@[Snapshot Sold To Industry Key Dsc]] In Licensee_List[#All] And Output The Value In Next Column To The Right.
```

Comment: thanks,the logic seems strange though. with this kind of hard coded checks, it will be difficult to automate!