# Excel formulas to pseudo code conversion required

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of relatively complicated excel formulas for which I need psuedo code,Can you guys help me out here? pasting oen such formula below

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Q",BnB_Filters[[#All],[Snapshot Spec Cd]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Atom",BnB_Filters[[#All],[EPM Name]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[CEDARVIEW]",BnB_Filters[[#All],[EPM Name]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("AY80609007614AA",BnB_Filters[[#All],[EPM Name]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("DG8065001313500",BnB_Filters[[#All],[EPM Name]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[PINEVIEW]",BnB_Filters[[#All],[EPM Name]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(922911,[@[Snapshot Confirmed Material Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(925482,[@[Snapshot Confirmed Material Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND(925443,[@[Snapshot Confirmed Material Id]])),IF(ISERROR(FIND("[PENWELL]",BnB_Filters[[#All],[EPM Name]])),"","Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"Atom"),"")`

Comment: What, you mean you can not describe in words what your formula does?

Comment: yes, I am not able to understand/decode what this formula is trying to  do:(

Comment: So, how did you write it?

Comment: legacy code:) trying to decode it and see if it can be converted to sql queries

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475760/how-to-understand-excel-formulas-to-convert-it-to-sql-query

Comment: Try rewriting formula in multiple lines and indenting it. Also see this (about values in square brackets): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select the cell with the formula, then use the Evaluate Formula tool (on the Formulas ribbon). It will step through the formula and you can take notes about each evaluation as each step progresses.

The formula you posted above is just a bunch of nested IF statements that uses structured references instead of A1 notation.

If you want to learn about structured reference notation, see 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx#BMstructured_reference_syntax_rules

Comment: Note: the "Evaluate Formula" tool isn't availbile on the mac I think...

Comment: @Joe, yah, well, nobody ever mentioned Mac. The list of things that work in Excel for Windows but not on Mac is very, very long (although they have been catching up over the last few years). Therefore, unless a question specifically mentions or tags with Mac, I will assume Windows, because that is just the biggest market share and the most comprehensive feature set.

Comment: thanks - I should have written "Note for other people arriving from google"